# How to return a view without a controller from Login.cshtml.cs?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I currently have a home controller which returns a view "Index.cshtml" which is only used to render my webpack's bundle.js for my Vue.js app.

home controller:

```
namespace AspNetCore.VueJs.Controllers
{
    [Route(ApiRoutes.Home.BaseRoute)]
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : BaseController<IEventService, EventDto, Event, int>
    {
        IEventService exampleService;

        public HomeController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IEventService exampleService) 
            :base(clientFactory, exampleService)
            {
            this.exampleService = exampleService;
            }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var x = exampleService.GetByIdAsync<EventDto>(1, new CancellationToken());
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
    @section styles{
    }
    @section scripts{
        <environment names="Development,Production,Staging">
            <script src="~/dist/js/home/bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
    }
    <div id="app">
    </div>
```

Currently after login the application gets redirected to the home controller as it's my base route.

I want to get rid of this controller as the only use of this controller is currently to return this Index.cshtml page. So When I login to my application I want to redirect the application to render the Index.cshtml page directly without using the controller.

In other words I still want Index.cshtml to be my base route and I need this to be rendered upon login but I want to achieve this without the home controller.

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a Razor Page. You can manually add a code-behind file (`Index.cshtml.cs`) and implement a `PageModel` derivation in that file, but it's probably easier to just add a new Razor Page. Then, you can just copy your existing view code into that, and modify the code-behind as necessary.

Comment: But how do I get my application to route to that index.cshtml after login and make it my base url?